# Spectral Representation for a real valued process

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory

So I just finished reading a section in a book which discusses how every stationary stochastic process $\xi(t)$ can be expressed as $\xi(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{it\lambda}\,dZ(\lambda)$ where $Z(\lambda)$ has orthogonal increments etc etc.

The book then goes on to mention a special case when the process $\xi(t)$ is real and that the above representation can be reduced to $\xi(t) = \int_0^{\infty}\cos{\lambda t}\,dU(\lambda) + \sin{\lambda t}\,dV(\lambda)$ etc. etc.

Does anyone know where I can find a proof for the representation for the real valued case? Hopefully a proof that's clear and easy to understand? Any lecture notes at hand? I've been looking but I can't find any...I might not be hitting the right keywords.